# Problem rendering cards with data that i bring from an API

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach

im trying to to render some pokemon cards with data that i bring from an API (pokemonAPI).
Im able to bring all the data that i need from the APi, exept for the type and abilities.
But that is not the main probles , as i already bring the most important data that i needed.
My problem comes inside the foreach that is un the renderPokemons function. Any clue of might i may solve this?

```
const getAllPokemons =  async (url) => {
    try {
        const pokemons = await fetch(url);
        return pokemons.json()
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
const getSinglePokemon =  async (url) => {
    try {
        const pokemon = await fetch(url);
        return  pokemon.json()
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',async (ev)=> {
    const URL  = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';
    const pokemons  = await getAllPokemons(URL);
    const pomekonDataPromises = pokemons.results.map (async pokemon => {
        const pokeTemp = await getSinglePokemon(pokemon.url)
        return {
            name: pokemon.name,
            weight : pokeTemp.weight,
            height : pokeTemp.height,
            // type: pokeTemp.types.type.name,
            image : pokeTemp.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default,

        }
    })
    const pokemonJson = await Promise.all (pomekonDataPromises)
    console.log(pokemonJson)

    const parentContainer = document.querySelector('.containerCards');
    renderPokemons(parentContainer,pokemonJson);
})

////FUNCTION TO RENDER POKEMONS
const renderPokemons = (parent,apiResponse) => {
    apiResponse.forEach((data) => {
        const parentTemplate = document.createElement('div');
        parentTemplate.innerHTML=`<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="img card-img-top" src="${data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default}" alt="Pokemon image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="name card-title">Name:</h5>
          <p class="weight card-text">Weight: </p>
          <p class="height card-text">Height: </p>
        </div>
      </div>`
      parent.appendChild(parentTemplate)
    });
}
```

Comment: You did not indicate pokemon's name, height and weight, so it won't be displayed

Comment: i know, i tried with the images first, but is not even bringing that. As it says that the problem is with the forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprites.other.dream_world.front_default` does not exist in `data`. That path exists in the original data, but not the object created in the event listener. It only has `name, weight, height, and image`. Changing it to `data.image` will work.

```js
const getAllPokemons = async(url) => {
  try {
    const pokemons = await fetch(url);
    return pokemons.json()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
const getSinglePokemon = async(url) => {
  try {
    const pokemon = await fetch(url);
    return pokemon.json()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async(ev) => {
  const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';
  const pokemons = await getAllPokemons(URL);
  const pomekonDataPromises = pokemons.results.map(async pokemon => {
    const pokeTemp = await getSinglePokemon(pokemon.url)
    return {
      name: pokemon.name,
      weight: pokeTemp.weight,
      height: pokeTemp.height,
      // type: pokeTemp.types.type.name,
      image: pokeTemp.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default

    }
  })
  const pokemonJson = await Promise.all(pomekonDataPromises)

  const parentContainer = document.querySelector('.containerCards');
  renderPokemons(parentContainer, pokemonJson);
})

////FUNCTION TO RENDER POKEMONS
const renderPokemons = (parent, apiResponse) => {
  apiResponse.forEach((data) => {
    const parentTemplate = document.createElement('div');
    parentTemplate.innerHTML = `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="img card-img-top" src="${data.image}" alt="Pokemon image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="name card-title">Name: ${data.name}</h5>
          <p class="weight card-text">Weight: ${data.weight}</p>
          <p class="height card-text">Height: ${data.height}</p>
        </div>
      </div>`
    parent.appendChild(parentTemplate)
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="containerCards"></div>
```